# Cosa vuol dire "in epoca storica" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Argon* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Susanna lo rifiutò, e Marchín si vendicò abominevolmente vendendo a un gòi la ricetta dei salami. È da pensare che questo gòi non ne abbia apprezzato il valore, dal momento che dopo la morte di Susanna (avvenuta in **epoca storica**) non è piú stato possibile trovare in commercio salame d’oca degno del nome e della tradizione. Per questa sua spregevole ritorsione lo zio Marchín perdette il diritto ad essere chiamato zio.

So che, secondo i dizionari, l'aggettivo "storico" fa riferimento a qualcosa "che appartiene alla storia", ma non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "in epoca storica" che appare in questo brano.

Significa che la morte di Susanna era avvenuta molto tempo fa e, per questa ragione, apparteneva già alla storia? Forse il senso è che questo fatto accadde in tempi memorabili o rilevanti per qualche ragione e che, per questa ragione, avevano "fatto storia" (accezione **1.f** del [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/storico))? Il significato è magari un altro?

Aggiungo un passaggio che dà un riferimento temporale alla vita di questa Susanna, per si può essere utile:

> La Susanna dei salami d’oca era cugina di Nona Màlia, mia nonna paterna, che sopravvive in figura di agghindata minuscola ammaliatrice in alcune pose di studio eseguite verso il 1870, e come una vecchietta grinzosa, stizzosa, sciatta e favolosamente sorda nei miei ricordi d’infanzia piú lontani.

Il racconto comincia in questo modo:

> Ci sono, nell’aria che respiriamo, i cosiddetti gas inerti. Portano curiosi nomi greci di derivazione dotta, che significano «il Nuovo», «il Nascosto», «l’Inoperoso», «lo Straniero». Sono, appunto, talmente inerti, talmente paghi della loro condizione, che non interferiscono in alcuna reazione chimica, non si combinano con alcun altro elemento, e proprio per questo motivo sono passati inosservati per secoli: solo nel 1962 un chimico di buona volontà, dopo lunghi ed ingegnosi sforzi, è riuscito a costringere lo Straniero (lo xenon) a combinarsi fugacemente con l’avidissimo, vivacissimo fluoro, e l’impresa è apparsa talmente straordinaria che gli è stato conferito il Premio Nobel.

Quindi, il narratore si situa nel tempo dopo il 1962.

Comment: Secondo me la prima interpretazione è quella corretta: lo interpreto come un modo di dire per indicare che l'avvenimento è avvenuto così tanto tempo fa da essere ormai considerata storia.
Espressioni simili potrebbero essere "passata ormai sui libri di storia" oppure "avvenuta in tempi immemori".

Se la morte fosse avvenuta poco tempo fa, l'espressione sarebbe stata "in epoca recente". "Epoca storica" è qui utilizzata come il suo contrario.

Comment: Credo che l'autore voglia dire “non proprio tanti anni fa”, in epoca storica e non preistorica.

Comment: Ho scoperto una [traduzione di Carmen Martín Gaite di questo racconto](https://books.google.es/books?redir_esc=y&hl=it&id=ccT4AgAAQBAJ&q=%C3%A9poca#v=snippet&q=%C3%A9poca&f=false) che fa la stessa interpretazione di @RiccardoDeContardi. Carmen Martín Gaite è stata anche lei una scrittrice importante, quindi sicuramente (come Pavese, Vittorini, Sereni, Fenoglio...) era una brava tradutrice.

Comment: Discordo: non ci si riferirebbe al personaggio con il solo nome. Questo sta a indicare che tutti sapevano chi fosse Susanna, quindi non poteva essere morta tanto tempo prima. Infatti era ancora viva durante l'infanzia dell'autore.

Comment: Va bene, @egreg: allora forse la conclusione sarebbe che non è possibile sapere con certezza qual è il significato dell'espressione nel testo. E [questa è la mia opinione su quello che si dovrebbe fare](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1419/) se si arriva a tale conclusione. (Non sappiamo se era viva durante l'infanzia del narratore, sappiamo che era viva la nonna, ma hai ragione che non poteva essere morta molti anni prima).

Comment: Credo che Levi adoperi spesso iperboli (come nel caso “non si usa più”, per esempio). L'avvenimento è sì di tanto tempo fa (storia), ma non così remoto da perdersi nella notte dei tempi (preistoria): l'epoca storica è quella di cui si hanno testimonianze.

Comment: Penso come @RiccardoDeContardi, è un modo per dire "tanto tempo fa".

Comment: @egreg: Se si tratta appunto di un'iperbole, allora, secondo me, va bene pensare che significhi "molti anni fa", anche se poi non siano veramente tanti.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vediamo dal dizionario Treccani per *[vulcano](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vulcano/)*:

> Tra le denominazioni dei tipi di vulcano: *vulcani attivi*, quelli che hanno avuto almeno una eruzione in **epoca storica**; *vulcani quiescenti*, caratterizzati da manifestazioni residue del vulcanismo attivo; *vulcani spenti*, in cui non si è riscontrata alcuna attività in **epoca storica**; [...]

(il nero è mio, per evidenziare l'uso di *epoca storica*). L'*epoca storica*, in contrapposizione a quella *preistorica*, è il periodo di tempo del quale abbiamo testimonianze di qualche tipo.

Ovviamente Levi non si riferisce alla preistoria, quindi il suo uso di *epoca storica* è iperbolico. Vediamo gli indizi:

1. Susanna è chiamata per nome, quindi nota ai personaggi del racconto;
2. era cugina della nonna che l'autore ricorda viva durante la sua infanzia;
3. “Il sistema periodico” è una raccolta di racconti basati su episodi della vita dell'autore.

Ne concludiamo che non può essere morta in epoca così remota, dopo tutto: ci si ricorda ancora di lei, perché aveva la ricetta del salame d'oca che nessuno sa più preparare come si deve dopo la vendita della ricetta al gòi. Si noti che la vendita avvenne quando ancora Susanna era viva, dopo il rifiuto di sposare Marchin. L'epoca è “storica” perché i personaggi del racconto ne hanno testimonianze di prima mano.

Se Levi avesse voluto collocare la morte di Susanna in tempi trascorsi da moltissimo tempo, avrebbe avuto molte altre scelte: *epoca remota* prima fra tutte. Non mi risulta che *epoca storica* possa essere adoperato in altro senso che quello detto all'inizio, se non con qualche attributo: *l'epoca storica di Dante*, *ogni epoca storica guarda il passato con…*.

Comment: Ah, @egreg: è davvero interessante questo esempio di uso dell'espressione "in epoca storica" che hai trovato!

Comment: Mi sa che Carmen Martín Gaite non aveva capito questo. Era una brava scrittrice, comunque.